# Altering PyQt5 QWidget from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 widget I am creating with the code below. After the button is pressed, I need to add an input box between the instructions QLabel and user QPushButton. The next time that button is pressed, I need to save the content of the input box to a key in node_dict.

The problem is since UserInputHandler is the function that will modify this code, I don't know how to alter the QWidget in this way since it's being created in the same function that calls UserInputHandler, so presumably I can't pass the QWidget as a parameter.

What is the proper way to accomplish this? Do I need to be using the class instead to create the QWidget?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * #For Gui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox #For Gui, redundant?
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt #For Gui
from selenium import webdriver as driver #For automation
import sys #For Gui

global node_dict
node_dict = {}

def UserInputHandler(driver, node_dict):
    if node_dict['step'] == 1:
        node_dict['product_page'] = driver.current_url
        print(node_dict['product_page'])
    return

def CreateNode(driver):
    global node_dict
    node_dict['step'] = 1
    container = QWidget()
    container.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint) #Doesn't work
    layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
    layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    instructions = QLabel('Click the button below to open a browser, then check back for more instructions', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    instructions.setWordWrap(True)
    instructions.setStyleSheet('color: white; background: black;')
    user = QPushButton('Open Browser')
    user.clicked.connect(lambda: UserInputHandler(driver, node_dict))
    info = QLabel('Lorem ipsum', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    info.setStyleSheet('color: white; background: black;')
    container.setMaximumSize(300, 200)
    layout.addWidget(instructions)
    layout.addWidget(user)
    layout.addWidget(info)
    return container

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("My awesome App")
        #self.showMaximized()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
central_widget = QWidget()
window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
node = CreateNode(driver)
layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
layout.addWidget(node)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Two things: 1) instead of using a function to create a widget, make a subclass of QWidget; this will allow you to create appropriate methods that will be correctly connected to (or disconnected from) signals. 2) the window flags you're trying to set will not work, as they are only valid for *top level widgets* ("windows"): as soon as you add them to a parent (like you did with `layout.addWidget(node)`), they will be simply ignored as those attributes are not considered for child widgets.

Comment: Ok thank you, it's working. I appreciate it.